# How to retrieve content passed back from remote server when the server reponds with a System.Net.WebException 422

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with an api that also returns a valid xml string containing the error that was encountered on their system.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
   <request>Request made to server</request>
   <message>No user found for account 12345</message>
</error>
```

Is there any way to get that xml from the remote server out of the System.Net.WebException object?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Direct from the MSDN docs:

> When [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) is thrown by a descendant of the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class,
>   the [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) property provides the Internet response to the
>   application.

So if you are if you are getting the exception while reading the response, you should just be able to read the Response property to get the XML contents.

Answer (score 1):

Sure ya can! Just need to throw a try-catch around your request.GetResponse(), catch a WebException and read from the exceptions Response property.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/ohnoa404");
WebResponse response;

try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    response = ex.Response;
}

String responseString = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: @user969602 Please accept if this solved your problem - It saves others coming here trying to find a solution